# Android Intent - Activity not Resumed

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having trouble resuming an activity.

Here's what happening:

**Activity A calls activity B :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Then Activity B Sets a Notification and calls Activity A:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MrpCastPlayerActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        intent, 0);

    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notif.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("TITLE")
            .setContentText("CONTENT")
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    notif.setOngoing(true);
  Notification notification = notif.build();
  NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

      notificationmanager.notify(0, notification);
      Intent intent2 = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
      startActivity(intent2);
```

The problem is when I tap the notification it opens **Activity B** but it does't call the `onResume` it calls `onCreate`. 
If I use `moveTaskToBack(true)`, instead of starting `intent2`, `onResume` is called. 
It seems that **Activity B** is finished when I use `intent2` to open **Activity A**.
Is there a away to avoid this ?

Comment: "it opens Activity B but it doesn't resume it" - can you provide more information on this

Comment: @Libin it opens the activity but doesn't call onResume, it's calls onCreate

Comment: can you post your manifest. Activity B android:launchMode should be "singleTop"

Comment: yes @Libin, android:launchMode="singleTop" is set.

Comment: can you post how you create pendingIntent instance?

Comment: I've update the question with the pendingIntent ;

Comment: Try changing the flag as PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, int, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: it also doesn't work, please read the last update of the question (bottom)

Answer (score 0):

To resume your activity, you should considering adding flags to your `Intent`.

do nothing inside the method onResume() and onstart() when coming back to this activity, Try this

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Manifest Changes:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"

              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

Hope this helps